# Json data in google chrome looking like a large string

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

Whenever I look into the Json data that comes back as a response i see it as a large string.
What do I have to do to see the data as a tree?
[How my response looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzTqM.png)
[How I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHv7G.png)

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest;

request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    //if request state is valid (4)
    if(request.readyState === 4){
        console.log(request, request.responseText);
    }
});

//create request with the 'GET'.
request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
request.send();
```

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText))`

Comment: JSON is nothing but a string that can be parsed into syntax that a JS runtime will understand. @Barmar provided the correct code to convert the string back into a JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to parse the data :

```
const result = json.parse(request.responseText);
```

*The parsing process will ignore the `\n`*

then you can properly log the json object as such :

```
console.log(result, null, 2);
```